# Python: read user-input directly from the prompt

Tags: python, events, interactive, prompt

I have to validate user-input from stdin that is not going to be entered by hitting the Enter-key. 
So readline() and other Enter-dependent functions are of no use to me.

Practically the promt will be filled, and each keystroke has to be handled as an event. How do I get access to the promt buffer's contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear what you mean by "prompt", but it sounds like you need to respond to individual key-presses, rather than textual input.

This is covered in the [Python FAQ](http://www.python.org/doc/current/faq/) under ["How do I get a single keypress at a time?"](http://www.python.org/doc//current/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time)

Answer (score 2):

See if it helps

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/